# Kotlin visibility view.gone crashed when clicked

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I was working on a 2nd screen for main activity, the 2nd screen(screen_overlay.xml) was something like an pop up overlay screen that the user can close anytime when pressed the textView.

the problem that i encounter is, everytime I click the "close screen" text, the app always crashed. i've been looking at some references about this, but almost all of the solution end up with the app crashed.

most of the solution that i found was written in Java, so i tried to adapt it in Kotlin, i still not sure where do i miss something or there is something wrong in the kotlin code below.

below is the xml code,

**screen_overlay.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.testApp.feature.screenView">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_close_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="CLOSE SCREEN"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="hideScreen"
            />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

below is the kotlin code,

**screenView.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.app.testApp.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.screen_overlay.*

class TutorialDialog : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_overlay)

        }

fun hideScreen(v: View?){
        val v:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView_close_screen)

        v.setOnClickListener{
            screen_background.visibility = View.GONE
        }

    }

}
```

Anyone help to fix this issue will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: you are adding click listener again and again. `hidescreen` should only contain `background.visibility = View.GONE`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh is there any explanation why `v.setOnClickListener` was added numerous times?

also i had try to remove the click listener, and only use `background.visibility = View.GONE` but it still crashed

Comment: you are finding the view again `findViewById ` and adding a new listener `v.setOnClickListener` which has been already done with `android:onClick="hideScreen" `

Comment: There are two issues. First why are you using nested constraint layout.
Second: You are not calling hide Screen in Activity Oncreate Method.

Comment: @dennisrufigill sorry about the first issue, i'm still new on kotlin programming, so i'm still not quite understand about putting nested layout. about the second issue, i had try to call the hide screen on Oncreate method before, but the app still crashed.

Comment: Is `R.screen_overlay` a typo? Because you should call `setContentView` with a layout reference ie. `R.layout.screen_overlay`.

Comment: @Dan please post your logcat error.

Comment: @Sandi yes, just fix it a second ago

Comment: You also cannot call `background.visibility = View.GONE` inside the `v.setOnClickListener` lambda because `background` is a property on `View` which returns a `Drawable`. Does the code snippet you posted even compile?

Comment: just added the logcat error. 

@Sandi just to inform you `background` in here is the name of the id of the constraint layout, the real id name is quite different, i had to censor it because some id contain private information. i just changed the id name into a easier one.

Comment: I just found out that the main problem wasn't on the code, but on the cache. it has to do with an "invalidate cache", after i clear the cache, the code was works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.app.testApp.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.screen_overlay.*

class TutorialDialog : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.screen_overlay)


        textView_close_screen.setOnClickListener{
            background.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        }


}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i just find out that you can immediately call the textview inside oncreate method. sorry but the problem still happening.

Comment: What is the problem now? @Dan

Comment: the problem are the app still crash after i click the `textView_close_screen`. there is also something bugging me about this, does it usually the overlaying of the 2nd activity to the main activity, will affect the whole app when the textview clicked?

Comment: You can put the button out of layout, in a separate layout @Dan

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just found out that the main problem wasn't on the code, but on the cache. it has to do with a "invalidate cache", after i clear the cache, the code was works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to hide the view once it's clicked:

```
fun hideScreen(v: View) = v.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: yes, that is my intention. so basically i have a main activity, and then the 2nd activity was pop up from the main activity which overlay the main activity, not completely overlay i think, but just like stacking up on top of it. then the user can hide the 2nd activity/view by click the close screen textview.